# Read value with hidden carriage return in boolean field as boolean

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I'm trying to read (dirty) CSV files from a cloud storage with PySpark which have `<boolean>\r`  values at the end of the line sometimes. This is not always the case, the column also contains correct booleans or even nothing (=null).

I get a schema from another place which specifies the column types (I have 200+ columns, the one in question is the last one). The column type for the last column is boolean - but since PySpark cannot interpret `True\r` values as `True` (same for `False\r`) I get nulls where I don't want to get nulls.

Data example:

```
id,mybool
1,True\r
2,False
3,
4,False\r
5,True
6,True\r
```

How can I ensure that PySpark can interpret the values?

I was thinking of editing the schema that I get and change the DataType to String, clean it up and cast it to Boolean, but I was hoping that there is a better way.

Comment: I do not think you have much choice but to go through the solution you proposed.

Comment: What’s the “normal” line ending, CRLF (\r\n) or something else?

Comment: Yes, \r\n is the one in all lines. I cannot determine what goes wrong during the data export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following option for now - replacing the DataType with StringType() and then using regex_replace to clean up the column:

```
df = df.withColumn("mybool", regexp_replace("mybool", r"\r", "").cast(BooleanType()))
```